# Go regexp find word with apostrophe

Tags: regex, go

I am trying to find a substring between two words, but my starting word contains an apostrophe and I can't seem to match it.

For example, in this following sentence

```
bus driver drove steady although the bus's steering was going nuts.
```

the correct answer to my search should be:

```
steering was going nuts
```

and not:

```
driver ... nuts
```

I tried this

```
re := regexp.MustCompile("(?s)bus[\\\'].*?nuts")
```

I also tried this:

```
re := regexp.MustCompile("(?s)bus'.*?nuts")
```

Can't seem to make it work.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I realized my mistake stemmed from the character class of the text I am parsing.

Comment: Bit shameless, but I previously wrote a package for exactly this purpose (pulling out any text between two strings/byte-slices): https://github.com/AlasdairF/Between

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [string literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals) (with back quote) in order to include a single quote, with a capturing group:

```
re := regexp.MustCompile(`(?s)bus'.\s+(.*?nuts)`)
```

See [this example](http://play.golang.org/p/4nAUjVwzUT):

```
var source_txt = `bus driver drove steady although the bus's steering was going nuts.`

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("Experiment with regular expressions.\n")
    fmt.Printf("source text:\n")
    fmt.Println("--------------------------------")
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", source_txt)
    fmt.Println("--------------------------------")

    // a regular expression
    regex := regexp.MustCompile(`(?s)bus'.\s+(.*?nuts)`)
    fmt.Printf("regex: '%v'\n", regex)
    matches := regex.FindStringSubmatch(source_txt)
    for i, v := range matches {
        fmt.Printf("match %2d: '%s'\n", i+1, v)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Experiment with regular expressions.
source text:
--------------------------------
bus driver drove steady although the bus's steering was going nuts.
--------------------------------
regex: '(?s)bus'.\s+(.*?nuts)'
match  1: 'bus's steering was going nuts'
match  2: 'steering was going nuts'
```

The [`FindStringSubmatch()`](http://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.FindStringSubmatch) :

> identifying the leftmost match of the regular expression in s and the matches, if any, of its subexpressions

The `match[1]` would be the first capturing group.

Comment: As you are already aware it was not the quote, it was the regex that was the problem. =)

Comment: @hwnd true. +1 to your answer. I always prefer using string literal for my regex though.

Answer (score 2):

> The correct answer to my search should be `"steering was going nuts"` ...

If you want that substring as your match result, you should adjust your regex accordingly.

```
re := regexp.MustCompile("(?s)bus's (.*?nuts)")
rm := re.FindStringSubmatch(str)
if len(rm) != 0 {
  fmt.Printf("%q\n", rm[0]) // "bus's steering was going nuts"
  fmt.Printf("%q",   rm[1]) // "steering was going nuts"
}
```

<kbd>[**GoPlay**](http://play.golang.org/p/o4abBAKn1E)</kbd>